# It is possible to push a docker image inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have a docker-in-docker container, which we'll call "dind". And a large image, which we'll call "LI".

Dind is responsible for make some *docker runs* calls. I need to run LI inside Dind. Normally, I push LI to a registry and pull it inside Dind. But I have a bad internet network. it takes a whole life to do this...

So, I was thinking if it is possible to push a docker image inside a docker container.

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're having?  Is there any reason you think it wouldn't work?  (Do you _need_ Docker-in-Docker; it's not really a setup that's usually encouraged?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to go over the network for this.

First, [save LI to a local tarball](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/#examples)

Then, in DIND use [docker import](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/import/#import-from-a-local-file).

Or alternatively, when you run DIND [mount the LI tarball directly](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume)

Answer (score 1):

You can use docker registry container in your localhost and pull image from it in dind. Here is the link: https://hub.docker.com/_/registry

Answer (score 0):

you have a image A and you need to run an image B in image A (as per my understanding)
you have a bad network-

your docker file should look like:

from image A
  docker pull image B

build this image and keep it as Image C

Image C should be your image for all the run which already has the Image B updated.
Pull and Push Image when the connectivity is strong and you should be good.